# Save Azure blob storage filename to Sql table - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

I have a **sales-2016-01.txt** file which I upload once monthly to the Azure blob storage. I want to process the **sales-2016-01.txt** file and save them to sql table. In addition to this I want to store the name of the file against each record in a separate column say ImportFileName. This is to track the record, from which file it was imported.

The filename will be dynamic based on the year and month.

I am using Azure Data Warehouse for storing the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but just for the record, in DF v2 in Copy Data activity, it is possible to add a new column to the source with value $$FILEPATH, and then each record will have a name of the input file.

[image: Azure DF v2, CopyData activity -> Source]

Comment: Just to add to this, you have to refresh your mappings in order to get the InputFileName to show as an option.  Or at least it didn't show until I did that.

Answer (score -3):

You can following the [MS sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-data-warehouse-connector/#_sample-copy-data-from-azure-blob-to-azure-sql-data-warehouse) to achieve this. You might need to modify a bit on the input dataset part in that sample since you only need the filename to be stored in the target table.

Comment: I am very new to azure, so a sample would be really helpful. I read other samples where they show how to define a structure but how to populate the filename for that column?

A sample code will be really appreciated.

Comment: I do not see where that example is accessing the blob filename.

Comment: @forester123, I either can't see that example is using blobfilename